# How does property 3 below involving a solution of trigonometric equation holds?

Tags: trigonometry

An edit has been made after reading some answers:

I recently encountered a seemingly simple trigonometry question which I cannot solve properly.

Consider the equation $\sin{(x+\frac{\pi}{4})}=-\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}}$.

Note that since $\sin{(x+\frac{\pi}{4})}=-\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}}$ it follows that

1. The equation above has two solutions $x$ in the interval $[0,2\pi]$.
2. $x>\frac{\pi}{2}$.
3. If $x$ is a solution to the above equation, then so is $\frac{\pi}{2}-x$.

I have trouble verifying 3. My question is how can I show that property 3 holds.

Note, I want to show in the end that If $x$ is a solution, then so is $\frac{\pi}{2}-x$ without using the expression $\frac{\pi}{2}-x$

Attempt:

I start with:

If $\beta=x+\frac{\pi}{4}$, then $\sin{\beta}=\sin{(2\pi-(\beta-\pi))}$.

From here, I do not know how to proceed and I do not now if the identity above holds.

Thanks for your help. Pictorial representation for the proof of result 3 will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be a solution to the equation. Then
$$\begin{aligned}
\sin\left(\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)&=\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}-x\right)\\
&=\sin\frac{3\pi}{4}\cos x - \cos\frac{3\pi}{4}\sin x \\
&=\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\cos x + \cos\frac{\pi}{4}\sin x \\
&=\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\
\end{aligned}$$
where in the penultimate line, I have used that $\sin\frac{\pi}{4}=\sin\frac{3\pi}{4}$ and $\cos\frac{3\pi}{4}=-\cos\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The question now was edited. But I upvoted your answer since it is correct.